# How can I force a NumberFormat on a VBA function result from the VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

Trying to convert timestamps that are given in seconds after Jan first 1970. I have written a small function in Excel VBA to convert to the Excel date format. This works fine in the sense that it converts to a number that if formatted correctly gives the timestamp in an intelligible way, but I have to format the calls by hand each time. I have tried to address the issue in several ways, but either it does not do anything to the number, or it results in an error: `"#VALUE."` The function is called `Sec2TS` and if I use: `1502569847` as input it returns: `42959.8547106481`, which is correct, but I would like to see: `2017 Aug 12 20:30:47`. I have added the code:

```
   Function Sec2TS(Secs As Double) As Date

If Secs > 0 Then
    Sec2TS = 25569 + (Secs / 86400)
Else
    Sec2TS = 0
End If

ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy mmm dd hh:mm:ss"

End Function
```

What is wrong with this? I have tried with set range to selection and toggling application, but to no avail.

Comment: If you're using this as a UDF, you can't. UDF's can't (except for some edge cases) modify the sheet.

Comment: Either pre-format the cell(s) to your NumberFormat, or return a date-as-a-string instead but be aware that a date in string form may not be ideal for your circumstance.

Comment: A workaround might be to use the Worksheet.Change event to reformat a cell once you've entered your UDF.

Answer (score 1):

If a formula could change formattings on a sheet, that would result in totally crazy effects for all users, because they would not know why all these odd things actually happen. That is probably the main reason why a formula/UDF cannot change anything in a worksheet, it can only return a value.

As workaround you can use the [Worksheet_Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) to format the cell right after you entered a formula that contains `Sec2TS`. So first we check wich cells of the changed range (`Target`) contain formulas (`Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`) and then check if any cell in this range contains `"Sec2TS"` in its formula to `.NumberFormat` this cells.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim CellsWithFormulas As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        Set CellsWithFormulas = Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    ElseIf Target.HasFormula Then
        Set CellsWithFormulas = Target
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If CellsWithFormulas Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CellsWithFormulas.Cells
        If InStr(1, Cell.Formula, "Sec2TS") > 0 Then
            Cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy mmm dd hh:mm:ss"
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Note that the `Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1` check is needed because if you apply `SpecialCells` to only one single cell VBA will apply it automatically to **all cells of the worksheet** which makes the code very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to process the values numerically, you can use `String` rather than `Date` as the function output:

```
Function Sec2TS(Secs As Double) As String
    Dim D As Double

    If Secs > 0 Then
        D = CStr(25569# + (Secs / 86400#))
    Else
        D = CStr(0)
    End If

    Sec2TS = Format(D, "yyyy mmm dd hh:mm:ss")
End Function
```

[image]